# JfreeChart: Scatter Plot moving X and Y Axises

Tags: plot, jfreechart, scatter

I just started using JFreeChart lib. I have a XY scatter chart with some negative plot points. The X and Y axises stay at the bottom and left sides of the chart, and they intercept at negative values. How can I make these axises intercept at (0,0) instead of intercepting at negative values?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A scatter plot uses an `XYPlot` and a `NumberAxis` for the domain and range. You can get each axis from the plot and invoke [`setLowerBound()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setLowerBound%28double%29), accordingly.

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
domainAxis.setLowerBound(0);
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setLowerBound(0);
```

Comment: Please edit the original question to clarify it. See `ScatterPlotDemo` http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp